# How to have a global .gitconfig for 2 or more git repos?

Tags: debian, configuration, git

This is my .gitconfig as it stands now :-

```
 $ cat .gitconfig
[user]
    name = Shirish Agarwal
    email = shirishagxyz@gmail.com
[credential]
    helper = cache --timeout=3600
```

This is in -

```
$ pwd
/home/shirish
```

Obviously I have obfuscated my mail id a bit to prevent spammers etc. from harvesting my mail id here.

But let's say I have another credential for another git site (private though) and I want to have it in the global configuration, both the username and the password so that when I pull from that site it doesn't ask me for the credentials anymore.

I am guessing this is possible, but how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. There are global configuration options and per-repository-options. If you use different email addresses in different repositories, you need to set them on a per-repository basis.

You can configure an individual repo to use a specific user / email address which overrides the global configuration.  From the root of the repo, run

```
git config user.name "Your Name Here"
git config user.email your@email.com
```

You can see the effects of these settings in the `.git/config` file .

The default settings are in your `~/.gitconfig` and can be set like this:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
git config --global user.email your@email.com
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig)

Comment: ok will try and let you know if it works, thanks.  But that does mean it would also generate a .gitconfig in that repository as well ?

Comment: *Every* git repo also has a `config` file, it's located at `.git/config` and created during the repo init.